# D3.js makes entity disappear while using animation function of A-frame

Tags: javascript, html, animation, d3.js, aframe

I'm trying to use animation property with D3.js, when I use a-animation in html part it works properly

```
<a-box id="box" position="0 1 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" color="#4CC3D9">
         <a-animation attribute = "position" to="0 1 -2" dur="1000" begin="mouseenter">
      </a-animation>
</a-box>
```

but when I try to append a-animation property in js part like this

```
d3.select("#box")
  .append("a-animation")
  .attr("attribute","position")
  .attr("to","0 1 -1")
  .attr("dur","1000")
  .attr("begin","click");
```

It makes entitiy disappear, I don't know why (Btw It creates the entity I can see in elements when I inspect from browser)

Is there any way to fix this problem ?
Is there any different way to make an object animate with d3.js?

Thanks for help.

Here is full code

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
       <a-box id="box" position="0 1 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" color="#4CC3D9">
         <a-animation attribute = "position" to="0 1 -2" dur="1000" begin="mouseenter">
         </a-animation>
       </a-box>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      d3.select("#box")
      .append("a-animation")
      .attr("attribute","position")
      .attr("to","0 1 -2")
      .attr("dur","1000")
      .attr("begin","mouseenter");
      </script>
      <a-camera><a-cursor></a-cursor></a-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got some input, though I'm not that familiar d3.

The entity dissapears, because its `rotation` attribute is set to `NaN 0 0`. 
You can see it in the inspector.

The attribute is being changed when You add an empty `<a-animation>`.
It does not matter if You do it through `d3.append("a-animation");`, or manually in html.

When using `d3.append("a-animation").attr(...)` You create an empty animation entity, and add attributes. I have no idea why adding attributes via `attr(...)` does not fix the 'rotation' issue.

So i came up with two ideas:

1. Use the `<a-animation>` entity, in a tricky way:

   - create an animation entity, and remove it from it's parent

   `var anim = d3.select("body").append("a-animation")
       .remove()
       .attr("attribute", "position")
       .attr("to", "0 1 -5")
       .attr("dur", "1000")
       .attr("begin","click");`

    I just appended it to the body, which is faulty ( I should use a-frame entities within the scene ), but I think it doesn't do any damage.

   - append it to the intended object using `appendChild` on the d3 nodes:
     `d3.select("#box").node().appendChild(anim.node());`

Why like this ? Because d3 `.append(...)` seems to require a html tag, not a html object reference.

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/soetzojt/1/.

2. Use the [animation component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation):
   It seems to work in a way, You would intend it to, because it's a component, not an entity. Causes no weird bugs. Doesn't need to be appended, just use the `attr()`:
   `d3.select("#box").attr("animation", {
       "property": "position",
       "dir": "alternate",
       "dur": "1000",
       "from": "0 1 -2",
       "to": "0 1 -5",
       "startEvents": "click"
     });`

This seems neater. Live fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/y0e7vfv3/2/.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried to use both your solution, second one fits but I couldn't use for two different animation for same entity, for example If I use property for position I couldn't use it for rotation or scaling. Do you know how can I use for multiple animation ?

Comment: @Melih the animation components need to have different names, animation__position, animation__scale, etc. Check out my updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/y0e7vfv3/3/

Comment: @Melih it's because i've used `dir: alternate`, just delete it, so it won't get back to its original state. For further options, check out the docs: https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation/

Comment: Thanks for helping I solved my problem both two answers. You don't need to answer my last problem. Have a good day !

Comment: @Melih glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use D3's native transitions, though there are some annoying quirks involved in getting them to work with A-Frame. Piotr's second example looks easier IMO.

For what it's worth, here is the JavaScript code from [this CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/bryik/pen/KvRJBP) that probably does what you want:

```
// Attach click event listener
d3.select("#box")
  .on("click", moveBox);

function moveBox () {
  // Select the box
  var box = d3.select(this);
  // Setup a transition
  box.transition()
     .duration(1000)
     // attrTween is needed for smooth transitions (IDK why)
     .attrTween("position", function() {
       // Get current position
       var currentPosition = box.attr("position");  // {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 0}
       // Return an interpolater from current to next position
       return d3.interpolate(currentPosition, {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": -2});
     });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The original code works fine if you move the javascript out of the a-scene container.